# Array of components in react does not render properly when updated

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I am trying to build a component containing an array of components in react, giving a new size to each component in array according to total number of elements. However the view does not update all the components. Only newly added component is updated with size even though i rebuild the array each time.

```
class StampArea extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {updateView: true};
    this.getStampSize = this.getStampSize.bind(this);
    this.prepareStamps = this.prepareStamps.bind(this);
    this.balance = 1;

}

prepareStamps(fulfill){
    var stamps = [];
    console.log('stamps: ', stamps);
    for (var i = 1; i <= fulfill; i++) { 
        if(i<=this.balance){
            stamps.push(<Stamp key={i} stampSize={this.getStampSize(fulfill)} stamped={true} stampBackgroundImage={this.props.stampBackgroundImage} stampPunchImage={this.props.stampPunchImage}/>);
        }else{
            stamps.push(<Stamp key={i} stampSize={this.getStampSize(fulfill)} stamped={false} stampBackgroundImage={this.props.stampBackgroundImage} stampPunchImage={this.props.stampPunchImage}/>);   
        }
    }
    console.log('stamps: ', stamps);
    return(stamps);
}

getStampSize(fulfill){
    if(fulfill >= 20){return 10}
    if(fulfill >= 15){return 20}
    if(fulfill >= 10){return 50}
    if(fulfill >= 8 ){return 35}
    if(fulfill >= 5 ){return 40}
    if(fulfill >= 4 ){return 60}
    if(fulfill >= 1 ){return 80}
}

render(){
    return( <div style={styles.stampsContainer}>{this.prepareStamps(this.props.fulfill)}</div>);
}

}

class Stamp extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.stamp=null;
    this.buildStamp=this.buildStamp.bind(this);
    this.buildStamp();
}

buildStamp(){
    // Assigning correct stylesheet to build the stamp as asked. 
        if(this.props.stamped){
            this.punched = (<img style={{position:'absolute',height:this.props.stampSize, width:this.props.stampSize, resizeMode:'contain'}} src={this.props.stampPunchImage}/>);
        }else{
            this.punched = null;
        }
            console.log('stampsize inside, ', this.props.stampSize);
            this.backgroundImage = (<img style={{position:'absolute',height:this.props.stampSize, width:this.props.stampSize, resizeMode:'contain'}} src={this.props.stampBackgroundImage}/>);
            this.stamp = (<div style={{position:'relative', margin:5,height:this.props.stampSize, width:this.props.stampSize}}>{this.backgroundImage}{this.punched}</div>);       
}
render(){
    return(this.stamp);
}
}
```

And here are some pics to explain better,

[The initial state always renders correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcQdd.png)

[This is how it looks when i update the component via props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1uoo.png)

Additionally when i check the array object, i see size props are set with correct value but somehow it doesn't render properly.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your render method just returns `this.stamp` which is generated only once inside the constructor. Instead of calling `buildStamp` inside a constructor, just move it inside render method and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works. I can't understand one thing. Doesn't constructor run every time i push a stamp into array? Or am i missing something.

Comment: @Taata It only runs once when the component is instantiated. It is the `componentWillUpdate` that gets executed every time the state/props changes. You can checkout the docs at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods

Comment: No, the constructor and componentDidMount only run once. You only create the object once, it just re-renders after that.